# AsyncTask and memory leaks

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am writing a simple map application downloading osm tiles from the server spawning a new AsyncTask for every tile. Some AsyncTasks run to completion, some are cancelled before they get a chance to run (in case I pan the screen). It may be then, when they appear to leak. I first discovered this by examining the lifetime of my tile bitmaps and saw they leak. After nulling the (indirect) reference to the bitmap in the AsyncTask, the bitmaps stopped leaking, but it got me pondering why said references matter and discovered that the number of AsycTasks continuously grows despite all efforts to close references to them. I ran MAT analysis and this is when i need help. Can anyone help me interpret the [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7k47s681q0rjkd/AsncTaskMemoryLeak.PNG) (sorry, I don't have enough stackoverflow browny points to attach images directly).

The tree entry shown presents one of many leaked AsyncTasks (of type FileCacheTask) with the children denoting all incoming references to it. I understand that the 'referent' is the garbage collector. The other two, denoted as this$0 (suggesting affinity with outer class) of type android.os.AsyncTask (this is in no way related to the outer class of FileCacheTask, admittedly FileCacheTask is a non-static inner class inside a tile factory), holding references to my leaked objects seemingly via mWorker members, is what i can't account for and can't obviously get rid of. I tried following the path and looking for incoming references to the android.os.AsyncTask objects but saw some scheduling internals and nothing related to my code). 
Any ideas what may be the android.os.AsyncTask objects referred to as this$0?

**EDIT**.
Following the advice, I have (kind of) distilled the problem to a digestible code snippet. I said kind of, as it does seemingly exhibit the same behaviour, but I can't be quite sure it truly suffers from the same problem. It still does behave cryptically. Here's the code:

```
public class TaskLeak {
static public int DDeletedTasks; //these are all for debug/tracing purposes
static public int DCreatedTasks;
static public int DCancelled;

private class PrivateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private int mTaskId;
    private boolean mFinished;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    public PrivateTask()
    {
        mTaskId = ++DCreatedTasks;
                //allocating a bitmap to give this object a meaningful weight for GC to consider.
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Log.d("Tasks", "(constructor) Task count:"+ mTaskId+" tasks in existence:"+(DCreatedTasks-DDeletedTasks));
        execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            int sleepForMs = mRandomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            //emulating blocking download action for a random few milliseconds.
            Thread.sleep(sleepForMs);
            //Log.d("Tasks", "Waking up from sleep, task:" + mTaskId);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //Log.d("Tasks", "Can't sleep, task:" + mTaskId);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        mFinished = true;
        maintain();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        DCancelled++;
        onPostExecute(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize()
    {
        ++DDeletedTasks;
        Log.d("Tasks", "(destructor) Task count:"+ mTaskId+" tasks in existence:"+(DCreatedTasks-DDeletedTasks));
    }       

    public boolean finished()
    {
        return mFinished;
    }       
}

private final static int KMaxTasks = 100;
private Random mRandomGenerator;
private final int mMaxCycles;
private int mCycles;
private final Vector<PrivateTask> mTasks;
public TaskLeak(int maxCycles)
{
    mMaxCycles = maxCycles;
    mRandomGenerator = new Random();
    mTasks = new Vector<PrivateTask>();
    for (int i = 0; i < KMaxTasks; i++)
    {
        mTasks.add(new PrivateTask());
    }
}

public void maintain()
{
    Log.d("Tasks", "***maintain(), tasks held:"+mTasks.size()+" there are "+ (mMaxCycles - ++mCycles)+" cycles left to go");
    for (int i = 0; i < mTasks.size();)
    {
        if (mTasks.get(i).finished())
        {
            mTasks.remove(i);
            if (mCycles < mMaxCycles)
            {
                mTasks.add(new PrivateTask());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if ((mCycles % 10) == 0 )
    {
        DCancelled++;
        mTasks.get(5).cancel(true);
    }

    if (mTasks.size() == 0)
    {
        new TestMemoryGrabber(200).test();
        Log.d("Tasks", "maintain() has finished!");
        Log.d("Tasks", "maintain(). There have been "+DCreatedTasks+" tasks created.");
        Log.d("Tasks", "maintain(). There have been "+DDeletedTasks+" tasks deleted.");
        Log.d("Tasks", "maintain(). There have been "+(DCreatedTasks-DDeletedTasks)+" tasks remaining.");   
        Log.d("Tasks", "maintain(). There have been "+DCancelled+" tasks cancelled.");
    }
}
```

When this is executed for 1000 cycles, it fails midway (on cycle #570) on out of memory exception, despite, at all times, i maintain no more than 100 references to the PrivateTask objects. This in itself is somewhat puzzling as GC should continuously make room for new entries. Why doesn't it?

Here's LogCat on about when the oom exception occurs:

```
01-12 16:37:50.902: D/Tasks(3235): (destructor) Task count:568 tasks in existence:156
01-12 16:37:50.993: D/Tasks(3235): ***maintain(), tasks held:100 there are 430 cycles left to go
01-12 16:37:51.062: I/dalvikvm-heap(3235): Clamp target GC heap from 49.251MB to 48.000MB
01-12 16:37:51.062: D/dalvikvm(3235): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 257K, 2% free 48337K/48903K, paused 70ms, total 71ms
01-12 16:37:51.062: D/Tasks(3235): (destructor) Task count:569 tasks in existence:156
01-12 16:37:51.092: D/Tasks(3235): ***maintain(), tasks held:100 there are 429 cycles left to go
01-12 16:37:51.222: I/dalvikvm-heap(3235): Clamp target GC heap from 49.251MB to 48.000MB
01-12 16:37:51.232: D/dalvikvm(3235): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 257K, 2% free 48337K/48903K, paused 139ms, total 139ms
01-12 16:37:51.242: D/Tasks(3235): ***maintain(), tasks held:100 there are 428 cycles left to go
01-12 16:37:51.312: I/dalvikvm-heap(3235): Clamp target GC heap from 49.502MB to 48.000MB
01-12 16:37:51.322: D/dalvikvm(3235): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 48593K/48903K, paused 70ms, total 72ms
01-12 16:37:51.322: I/dalvikvm-heap(3235): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 262160-byte allocation
01-12 16:37:51.412: I/dalvikvm-heap(3235): Clamp target GC heap from 49.494MB to 48.000MB
01-12 16:37:51.412: D/dalvikvm(3235): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 1% free 48584K/48903K, paused 86ms, total 86ms
01-12 16:37:51.412: E/dalvikvm-heap(3235): Out of memory on a 262160-byte allocation.
01-12 16:37:51.412: I/dalvikvm(3235): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-12 16:37:51.412: I/dalvikvm(3235):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a14568 self=0x2a00b9e0
01-12 16:37:51.412: I/dalvikvm(3235):   | sysTid=3235 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073870640
01-12 16:37:51.412: I/dalvikvm(3235):   | schedstat=( 21236163363 7517071458 4002 ) utm=1940 stm=183 core=0
01-12 16:37:51.412: I/dalvikvm(3235):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
01-12 16:37:51.412: I/dalvikvm(3235):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
01-12 16:37:51.412: I/dalvikvm(3235):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
```

Comment: logcat/part of code with async task -  please put it here, please

Comment: It's hard to help you without posting code, but here's a tip after reading your post:  It goes against best practices to fire off AsyncTasks in the way you describe.  Check out the "Order of Execution" section here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html As of Honeycomb (Android 3.0), there is only one thread in the AsyncTask pool, so your tile downloading will happen serially on any Android version post-Gingerbread.  Using a custom ThreadPool will alleviate this potential problem, and in the process may help with your memory leak, too.

Comment: Thanks for the first attempts. What i'll do is try distilling the problem to a digestible/concise piece of code that demonstrates the behvaiour and repost. May take me one or two days. @Matt: exactly which aspect of my implementation goes against best practices? The fact that I am spawning tile-per-task instead of implementing a queue of tiles and having single task process the queue?

Comment: You've got it exactly.  While what you're describing isn't necessarily wrong, I get the impression you're firing off many AsyncTasks at the same time or in a short amount of time.  It'll be important for you to know that while these downloads are happening asynchronously from your main thread, they happen serially with respect to each other.  If you have a small amount of tiles (and it's great that you're canceling threads if they're no longer needed), this might not be so bad, but a user randomly panning around the screen or the thread hanging on a single tile could cause a performance hit.

Comment: And any other operation that you start an AsyncTask for (such as db access) will wait for any previous tiles to download first. Your idea to have a task process the queue could help this.  Alternatively, if you want all the tile downloads to happen concurrently, you can create some type of structure where you create jobs for your tiles and hand them to a ThreadPoolExecutor: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html  This is an aside from your main problem though, and I'll be happy to try and help you with that once you've updated your question.

Comment: @MattDavis: I clearly see 5 instances of AyncTask thread in execution on my 4.1 emulator and i clearly see stuff happening on others whilst i arrest one of them (say on a breakpoint). Ergo: i must be running a pool of threads and that's certainly better for my tile downloading performance and it defends my design. Still kind of leaks and I can't rest my case.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, logs, and explanation, I'd guess that this OutOfMemoryError caused by having too many Bitmaps stored in memory.

When you create each PrivateTask, before it even starts to run, you're initializing a Bitmap to be kept in memory.  With over 100 tasks in existence, you are pushing up against your memory limit.  Logcat lines such as the following indicate this:

```
01-12 16:37:51.412: D/dalvikvm(3235): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 1% free 48584K/48903K, paused 86ms, total 86ms
```

As for mitigating the problem, the number 1 solution I can recommend is making sure that once each task it canceled, you explicitly call `recycle()` on your Bitmap objects.  I'd suspect that even though the PrivateTasks are being canceled, some reference to them is being maintained, which is causing only a very small amount (1%ish) of your memory to get freed when GC occurs because the system just isn't destroying them or, in turn, your Bitmaps.  Alternatively, GC could be handling this exactly correctly, but there are enough Bitmaps in your active PrivateTasks to push you to the memory limit, which would also lead to nothing being garbage collected because the system can't find anything to collect!  If you regularly need to download so many Bitmaps from your server, you may want to look into storing them on disk and only retrieving them into memory as needed, though this could cause a significant performance hit.

Here are some links and other SO questions concerning Bitmap management:

[Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently from the Android Dev Site](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) (See especially the section on Caching Bitmaps)

[Solutions for someone who had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950658/android-bitmap-memory-use)

[You could try compressing the Bitmaps once they finish downloading, depending on quality. Remember to recycle the reference to the original after compression!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296217/need-help-in-handling-images-in-android)

[More info on what's going on under the hood when you allocate memory for a bitmap.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945142/bitmaps-in-android)

As a side note, I'm curious as to what type of device/emulator you're testing this on, especially the SDK version.  The amount of memory provided for an Android app has increased with newer hardware, so you may see different results testing on different phones.  Additionally, I still think it's possible that many devices (a growing number, as Gingerbread loses market share and ICS/Jellybean gain) will perform these operations serially, which will also change the results you're getting, though doesn't seem to be the root of this specific issue and would be more of a concern for future-compatibility of your app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks again Matt., but this isn't where the trouble is. The code above is only a good simulation of what i really run and what i really run doesn't have a problem with bitmap management. The bitmaps feature above in order to (and as commented): "give this object a meaningful weight for GC to consider.". Yes, the OOM exception occurs because of having too many bitmaps stored in memory, but why is there so many, if my code only keeps references to 100? Why do I then observe 156 bitmap holding tasks in existence at the point of OOM. Why doesn't GC release them to serve memory hungry requests?